# Create an email with a meeting invitation attached

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am working on an Excel workbook to track appointments and to send an email to advise of the appointment.

I put together code to open an email in Outlook with inputs pulled from the Excel sheet.

```
Sub ButtonREMINDER41_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng = 
Sheets("Sheet1").RangeToHtml("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible, xlTextValues)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
       vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If

With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

`Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = Range("$F$41")
.CC = Range("$B$41")
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Upcoming Scheduled Appointment"
.HTMLBody = Range("$N$41")
' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
' display the e-mail message.
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

I am trying to also book an appointment in the receiver's calendar.

I would like an email generated with a meeting attachment for the appointment.

Comment: You are creating a Msg Item (email) you need to create a Meeting item and go from there. These two lines will open the meeting: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) | OutMail.MeetingStatus = olMeeting replace your Set OutMail line with the these.

Comment: I am creating a message so it can also send that message to a cell phone as an SMS. if i create a meeting than i lose that ability right?

Comment: Adding  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) | OutMail.MeetingStatus = olMeeting replace your Set OutMail line with the these. worked to open the message but for some reason the code is not pulling the email address in cell F2. is there code to pull the date and time from the excel spreadsheet and carry into the start and end time in the message?